# Binding kendo treeview from remote data not working

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to bind a kendo treeview from the remote data but the data is not getting binded.

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: App.toRestUrl('/ServerController'),
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",                        
                    objname: "objname"
                    hasChildren:false,
                }
            }
        });

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: homogeneous,
            dataTextField: "objname"
        });
```

This is what i am doing in javascript file.

I am returning data as a list from serverside(c#)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Raghu

Comment: How does the response from the server look like?

Comment: not enough info to provide any assistance... we need to know how the server responds when the API is called

Comment: Typical error is that server does not send back an `array` but an `object`. Try opening in your browser `App.toRestUrl('/ServerController')` and check that is a JSON array.

Comment: I agree with @OnaBai.  Check your JSON response to ensure it's correctly formatted and returned correctly. An additional comment for the curious - the hierarchicaldatasource requires a items source to correctly identify child items, so extend your schema to include a items mapping.